# why is my ic_launcher icon smaller than GooglePlay App's icons?

Tags: android, icons

I have following issue, am developing an App for Android and I realise that the launch icon AKA ic_launcher is quite smaller than al the rest of the App that I got from GooglePlay.!see image below.. I tried as normal (on eclipse: new->android icon-set->....) using a 512x512 png file, then I gave a 2nd try using a recommended link I found by searching a solution ([Android Asset Studio](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html))
you may want to say " is not tooo much" but that is what I need, must be the same size as normal apps...

thanks in advance!

see the dotted line as reference to verify the size
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create icon 512x512px without any generators, they add margins to a picture. You have to draw icon from border to border.
Use an existing application icon as a template, for example - mine

[image: my icon]